# C# Form1.cs no longer showing in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to programming and am working on a C# project and my form1.cs is no longer in my solution explorer. It does however show in class view. I have tried right clicking and adding existing item but this doesn't work. Is it possible to get the form1.cs back from class view into solution explorer? Thanks.

Comment: Did you rename the file somehow and select "no" when it asked you to refactor?

Comment: I didnt change anything. I don't know what happened.

Comment: What "doesn't work" when you try to add it back in? What is the error you get?

Comment: When I add existing item I click on the form1.cs but it doesn't add to the solution explorer. When I try and run the program it gives the error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

Comment: See if this helps: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef?auth=1 I don't know what version of VS you are using, but its possible your redistributables have gotten corrupted. Either try that or do a repair on the VS installation.

Comment: @Eim - is the file physically present on the hard drive at the location of the project?

Comment: @Ahmed Salman Tahir it is yes

Comment: see also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/24af7f37-cc97-4c46-a265-e94005223e4c/visual-studio-solution-explorer-not-showing-form-cs-file

Answer (score 1):

Try to click "Show all items" button on top of Solution Explorer, it will show all files that not in your project. And if your Form.cs will appear then right click on it and select "Include in project" menu.

Comment: @Eim, then try to look this file in other project folders, may be you accidentally moved it by mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the form has got excluded from your project. At the top of your Solution Explorer, click "Show All Items".

[image]

If the form then appears, right click it and select "Include In Project".

**UPDATE**
From what has been said, it sounds like the Form.cs file may have got "disconnected" from the designer and resx files. Close Visual Studio and open the .csproj file in an XML editor or just Notepad and check that you have something resembling the following in an "ItemGroup" element.

```
<Compile Include="Form1.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Program.cs" />
<Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Make any changes required and then re-open your solution.

Comment: Is it still in the file system, i.e. if you open the project in File Explorer, is it still there? You also need to have the projected selected where it should be when you "Show All Items".

Comment: @Eim I edited my comment so you may have missed the edit but do you also still have the Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.resx files in the same location. I think you could also try dragging Form1.cs into the Solution Explorer as well.

Comment: Yes both are present in the same location. And both are in the solution explorer.

Comment: @Eim, I've updated my answer based on what you have said.

Comment: Did this actually bring back the form for anybody? I seriously doubt this has anything to do with the vanishing form file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and was struggling with it quite a while.
I solved it by installing the desired target framework (in my case **.NET 4.5.1**) manually (from offline installer) AND the **.NETCoreApp** components (from "modify" in the VS installer).

Then I created a new solution with a console project in it and set the target framework to .NET 4.5.1.

When I now create a new Forms project, everything is back to normal (it uses 4.5.1 by default) and the `Forms.cs` file shows up in solution explorer.

I will try if I can fix my broken projects that way too...

In my `.csproj` file there was no

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Not before and not after the `Form.cs` was shown.

Comment: Really weird: It seems if I have a .NetCore console project in the solution, it works (after a couple of random load/unload project, clean/build, close/open VS2017). It just reappeared.

Comment: Sorry, after a restart it was gone again. I guess I will have to keep the console app in the solution, as I don't want a SDK dependency in the Forms project.
P.S.: Down vote without comment?!

Comment: Just for the others: Whoever down-vote obviously didn't try it:-) I am using this hack for a couple of weeks now and it behaves exactly as described.

Comment: Absurdly enough this works: Adding a .NET Standard class library project to the solution, and the solution explorer foldout shows the classes again.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click and select "Exclude From Project" then Right-click and select "Include In Project" the same model; And you will see the file