# Visual studio solution explorer not showing form cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

Cant find user code file of Windows form in solution explorer, now I must right click on form class and choose <>View Code. But there always been cs file at the bottom of class.
[image]

Comment: Also, why are you still using windows forms?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Probably because (sadly) it's still being taught (at the community college I work part-time at, anyway).

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand the question here; isn't the `.cs` file the one you are highlighting?  why would there be another `.cs` file associated with it?

Comment: @Claies There are two cs files with every form, a designer.cs file that holds all the generated code, and a standard one for user code.

Comment: which both appear to be present in the screenshot?

Comment: @Claies He's saying there used to be an explicit link to it in solution explorer, now he has to use the "View Code" option to get to it. OP, are you asking how to get this back? You may just have to live with it.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can always open the code view by selecting the form and pressing your F7 key.

Comment: check the properties of your form.  Is it's build action set to `compile` or to something else? i.e. `none`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923422/c-sharp-form1-cs-no-longer-showing-in-solution-explorer

Answer (score 3):

Same error here.

Visual Studio Professional 2015. Version installed: 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 (with the KB3165756)

This wrong behaviour started after installing Azure SDK 2.9.6, that installs .NET Core stuff & .NET Core templates into Visual Studio 2015 (actually installed .NET Core Tools (Preview 2) 14.1.21111.0)

If you add Class Library (.NET Core) or Console Application (.NET Core) to your C# solution, the forms.cs become visible again in solution explorer

Before adding Class Library (.NET Core):

[image]

After Class Library (.NET Core) added to Solution:

[image]

There is *something wrong* with .NET Core stuff. Hopefully it fixes on future patches.

Comment: This actually works. Add a new .NET Standard project to your solution, and the solution explorer foldout starts showing the contained classes again. VS 2017 professional here ...

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the default editor for your files?

Right click on form.cs file:

[image]

Select your desired editor an click the *Set as default* button

- **Csharp Form Editor:** Opens your form on design view.
- **Csharp Editor:** Opens your code view.

[image]

Comment: My editors were fine, but thanks for the hint anyways. It would have been way more logical if it were the editors :-)

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Now you just open the code instead of the designer. In VS2015 you had one file for the code and one file for opening the designer. This is missing now in VS

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue, not displaying my Form. What you should do is:

- `/project_directory/project_name.csproj` edit this file and make sure your_form_name.cs is like this:

Notice: first delete all records from this file with existing your_form_name.cs and add the following:

```
`<Compile Include="your_form_name.cs">
   <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="your_form_name.Designer.cs">
   <DependentUpon>your_form_name.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="your_form_name.resx">
   <DependentUpon>your_form_name.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>`
```

Open solution again and Form will be shown in your project once again.

Comment: I had to do this, and also move a class that I had above my form class in the same file... Visual Studio didn't like that for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not best solution but after complete removing and installing Studio returns to its normal state.
[image]

Comment: Re-installing didn't do the trick for me... Did you do anything special while removing?

Comment: Not sure maybe I deleted this folders
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2019 and the same problem was for me.
But I solved this issue.
I used Visual Assist for VS2019 and after expiration I uninstalled it.
After that I got this issue.
So I re-installed it again and licensed it.
Then, it works now.