# Form class file hidden in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

I have encountered a problem that appeared this morning. I have a Windows Forms project, but within the "Form" file folder, the Form1 class file that contains my code (that usually can be accessed in the by double-clicking on the "Form1" class file) - have suddenly disappeared from the Solution Explorer.

I can, however access it by right-clicking on the Form1 folder and selecting "View code". The problem occurs in all the projects that I have opened. The only files shown within the "Form1"-folder are Form1.Designer.cs and Form1.resx.

Do you guys have any idea how to "reset" the Solution Explorer window to behave as before? I attached a screenshot of my Solution Explorer view, after selecting "View code".

[image: Screenshot]

This is what it used to look like:

[image]

Comment: You can always select it and press F7.

Comment: It looks and behaves completely normal, I doubt anybody could guess what it looked like before.  You don't have real problem.

Comment: This question seems similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916624/visual-studio-solution-explorer-not-showing-form-cs-file It was resolved by reinstalling Visual Studio

Comment: This is how it used to look like: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/images/csharp_2013/first_form/form_designer_sol_expl.gif