# Visual Studio is not displaying the .cs code file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Recently my Visual Studio 2015 stopped showing the .cs file containing the code. The result of this is:

> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

This is a Windows Forms Application (Yes I know, why?) and the forms usually have three files in its structure. The .Designer.cs, the .resx and the .cs files. the .cs completely disappeared in VS. Even toggling the "Show All Files" button on the Solution Explorer does not show it. I checked and the files still exists and when viewing the Form, hitting F7 takes you to the code.

I have tried restarting VS and my PC, resetting the VS's settings and repairing VS. All with no luck. The only thing I found that I haven't tried is to completely uninstall VS and it's related files and installing it again. I really hope I can avoid this. So please let me know if there is another way to fix this?

Comment: Can you manually re-add the files to the project?

Comment: Visual Studio can't show a *deleted* file. Resetting or repairing VS won't fix this either. First of all, is the file still there? Were any changes made to the project? Does the file or form use some component that causes a designer exception?

Comment: Select the project and then click the button "Show all files". you´ll see the CS file now. Right click it and 'Add to solution'. Try that.

Comment: There is show-hide button at right corner of soluction explorer. Click there ,you will find the hidden file.

Comment: You should seriously consider using version control like Git so when such things happen in the future, you'll be able to see what changed and fix it. Such problems are typically caused by mistakes, not bugs

Comment: @PaulStelian I will give that a try, thanks.

Comment: I saw you said that the Show/Hide All Files isn't working, however if the .cs file is there if you look through Windows Explorer, try deleting the file in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer. That should only remove it from the Project, but remove all three versions of the "file". Now does it appear in Show/Hide All Files? (There is a possibility that it got sent to the Recycle Bin, so go there and Restore all three files and try again.)

Comment: Another option would be to open the Designer file, and hit either F7, or Shift-F7 (I forget which one goes in which direction), but that is the keystroke to go between the designer and code behind files. Visual Studio __might__ be able to "recover" the code behind that way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the files are not deleted and it is only my VS that is giving this issue, the other developers are fine. We are using source control, but this issue started without updating the source code and it was fine the previous time that I worked on it.

Comment: And *now*? What's the diff with the commited code? If the file *is* there it will appear if you click on `Show All Files` - unless you are in a different folder by mistake.

Comment: Possible Visual Studio 2015 & .NET Core bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44024061/3122306